# GROUP BY in SQL Server across three tables

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have found that I don't know how to group results of query in SQL Server. I have SQL Server 2005 with three tables:

**domains:**

```
- id
- name
```

**entity:**

```
- domain_id
- user_id
```

**users:**

```
- id
- login
```

So, it's common relationship between two tables across third table, where several domains may relate to one user.

T-SQL query:

```
SELECT domain.name, users.login 
FROM domain, entity, users 
WHERE domain.id = entity.domain_id AND entity.user_id = users.id 
GROUP BY users.login, domain.name
```

returns:

```
+------+-------+
| name | login |
+------+-------+
| dom1 | user1 |
| dom4 | user1 |
| dom5 | user1 |
| dom2 | user2 |
| dom3 | user3 |
+------+-------+
```

My question is how to create T-SQL query which returns same as MySQL:

```
SELECT domain.name, user.login 
FROM domain, entity, user 
WHERE domain.id = entity.domain_id AND entity.user_id = user.id 
GROUP BY user.login

+------+-------+
| name | login |
+------+-------+
| dom5 | user1 |
| dom2 | user2 |
| dom3 | user3 |
+------+-------+
```

Comment: Your query should work in both MySQL and SQL Server.  Is it possible that the content of your tables is different?

Comment: @Andomar: The 2nd query has the `domain.name` missing from the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @ypercube: Right, surprising tho, since I'd expect SQL Server to return an error for the missing `group by` column

Comment: I don't understand what you are grouping for.  What information are you trying to get from this data?

Comment: Jim, I need a list of domains grouped by users. I don't know how to explain more clear. It's ok if not all domains will be selected, it's necessary for me because in my code I have to access to each user, but i can do this only via domain, and it doesn't matter which one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a MS SQL (and most standard implementations) that returns the same as MySQL

```
SELECT MAX(domain.name), user.login  
FROM domain, entity, user  
WHERE domain.id = entity.domain_id AND entity.user_id = user.id  
GROUP BY user.login
```

In both environments, the FROM / WHERE join would be better expressed as

```
FROM domain
    INNER JOIN entity
         ON domain.id = entity.domain_id 
    INNER JOIN user  
         ON entity.user_id = user.id
```